# Making requests asynchronously using httpx not much faster when getting big zip files

Tags: python, asynchronous, request, httpx

I'm having an interesting problem where using httpx to make requests asynchronously doesn't improve runtimes over making requests synchronously when getting big-ish zip files.

This is my current test code, where I try to download a random file from the Census (around 5MB).

```
import asyncio
import time
import httpx
import requests

async def main():
    n = 25
    url = f'https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020/PLACE/tl_2020_01_place.zip'
    
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = [client.get(url) for _ in range(n)]
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print('httpx time:', end_time-start_time)

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    session = requests.Session()
    responses = [session.get(url=url) for _ in range(n)]
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print('sync time', end_time-start_time)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I run the code, both trials take basically the same amount of time. Sometimes one is faster than the other, but they average to around the same.

Anyone have any ideas? Is some part of reading in the files (as opposed to just making the requests) blocking?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: download two at a time, and the asyncio version will be much faster.  essentially, asyncio is about being able to do other things while you are waiting for I/O.  there's nothing in asyncio that will make it download from the internet faster.

Comment: @toppk Thanks for the feedback. Tried that. Switched my test to 10 consecutive rounds of trying to get 2 at a time. Still about the same speed as just getting 20 in a row. Is it possible that getting more at a time just slows the request down so much that it ends up not helping?

Comment: yes, I think you got it.    There's only a slight overhead in the sync case as the requests are serializes after each response.  but that's going to be minor.  I did get a slight improvement by creating an AsyncClient for each task, so there's probably some to look into there, but overall you'd expect one file to be sent as fast as the connection allows, so parallel requests are only going to eat into that, as you are observing.